# finding a minimum repeatedly over the same array

Tags: c, arrays, minimum

I am trying to repeatedly find the minimum over an unsorted array without using any additional data structure if possible. This array is an input buffer which is being loaded from a file on disk. When finding the 2nd minimum, how do I make sure that it does not reconsider the 1st minimum which has already been selected. Similarly while finding the 3rd minimum the 1st and 2nd min should not be considered and so on.

I cannot set the minimums to a certain value like -1, since -1 might be an input integer.

Comment: What do you mean by "first minimum"? What do you mean by "reconsider"? Do you just want to find the smallest number? Or the indexes of the smallest number?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you gave an example input of, say, 20 numbers, and the output you want to produce.

Comment: can you please explain with some sample test cases ?\

Comment: Generally people will solve this by sorting the input... then each next minimum is just the next entry in the sorted array.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/558729/optimum-search-for-k-minimum-values-in-unsorted-list-of-integers

Answer (score 2):

You could swap the minimum with the last item in the array, then consider one less element the next time you search.

Or just sort the whole array, as @mah mentions in the comments.

Which one is more efficient depends if the number of elements you need to fetch is <> lg(N)

Comment: Yes, but its like in an array of 1000. I have allocated 0-3 to elements from file 1, 4-8 to elements from file 2 and so on for 250 files. so swapping would disrupt this.

Comment: If you can't modify the array, I would insert the array indexes in a priority queue (doing comparisons on A[i], not i). Then just pull off as many minimums as you need in O(NlgN).

Answer (score 0):

You should save the index of the first minimum in a variable and recalculate the 2nd minimum for all elements of the array except the index of the first minimum.

Comment: that works for the 2nd, but doesn't scale to the 100th well.

Comment: Yeah. I did something like that. kept track by using another array.